# Split video into smaller timed segments in Java

Tags: java, video, split

I am looking to take a large video files (3hours+) and pass in segments of the video that I would like to split.

For example, I could pass in a 3 hour video - and want from 00:10 to 00:11 to be split into a separate file.

I currently have the below code - that takes my video and splits it into a split no. of segments, but how would I go about splitting the video by time instead?

Code:

```
            try {
                File file = new File("//Users//robeves//Desktop//Videos to split//TestVideo.mp4");//File read from Source folder to Split.
                if (file.exists()) {

                String videoFileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")); // Name of the videoFile without extension
                File splitFile = new File("//Users//robeves//Desktop//Videos to split//Converted//"+ videoFileName);//Destination folder to save.
                if (!splitFile.exists()) {
                    splitFile.mkdirs();
                    System.out.println("Directory Created -> "+ splitFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                int i = 01;// Files count starts from 1
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                String videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ String.format("%02d", i) +"_"+ file.getName();// Location to save the files which are Split from the original file.
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                System.out.println("File Created Location: "+ videoFile);
                int totalPartsToSplit = 20;// Total files to split.
                int splitSize = inputStream.available() / totalPartsToSplit;
                int streamSize = 0;
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {

                    if (splitSize == streamSize) {
                        if (i != totalPartsToSplit) {
                            i++;
                            String fileCount = String.format("%02d", i); // output will be 1 is 01, 2 is 02
                            videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ fileCount +"_"+ file.getName();
                            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                            System.out.println("File Created Location: "+ videoFile);
                            streamSize = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    outputStream.write(read);
                    streamSize++;
                }

                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                System.out.println("Total files Split ->"+ totalPartsToSplit);
            } else {
                System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath() +" File Not Found.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probablyneed a video library to parse your video file, as the timing differs from format to format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do want to be able to play the segments individually, then the above code may not work if it is just splitting the file at arbitrary points, as many video formats need to finish on a good 'boundary' to enable proper playback.

As Binkan suggests, using a video library like ffmpeg, either in cmd line, wrapped cmd line or by using its associated C libraries, will allow you safely split a video in most common formats.

For example the following ffmpeg cmd line will create a segment from an mp4 video:

ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -c copy outputVideoSegment.mp4

The following code uses this utility in a 'wrapper' to segment a video file into chunks:

```
        int chunkSize = videoDurationSecs/(numberOfChunks + 1);
        int startSecs = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfChunks; i++) {
            //Create video chunk
            String startTime = convertSecsToTimeString(startSecs);
            int endSecs = startSecs + ((i+1)*chunkSize);
            if (endSecs > videoDurationSecs) {
                //make sure rounding does not mean we go beyond end of video
                endSecs = videoDurationSecs;
            }
            String endTime = convertSecsToTimeString(endSecs);

            //Call ffmpeg to create this chunk of the video using a ffmpeg wrapper
            String argv[] = {"ffmpeg", "-i", videoPath, 
                    "-ss",startTime, "-t", endTime,
                    "-c","copy", segmentVideoPath[i]};
            int ffmpegWrapperReturnCode = ffmpegWrapper(argv);
        }


        String convertSecsToTimeString(int timeSeconds) {
            //Convert number of seconds into hours:mins:seconds string
            int hours = timeSeconds / 3600;
            int mins = (timeSeconds % 3600) / 60;
            int secs = timeSeconds % 60;
            String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, mins, secs);
            return timeString;
        }
```

Examples of wrappers are here, but you can also use the ffmpeg libraries directly if you would rather avoid the wrapper approach (which does have the disadvantage that ffmpeg cmd line is not really intended to be wrapped in this way):

- http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/
- https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg (Android based)

Comment: Thanks Mick. This seems like a good idea - I'll have a play around tonight and will let you know how it goes. Thanks again, Rob.